# PHP like query not find any results when using hebrew language

Tags: php, mysql

I hope its allowed and i am not bothering here every 5 minutes with new questions but i need help at this .

I have this code , i got it from my last question before :

```
          $string = $purifier->purify(@$_POST['string']); 

          $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_fname like '%".$string."%' OR user_lname like '%".$string."%' OR username like  '%".$string."%' OR useremail like '%".$string."%'";
          mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
          $result2 = mysql_query($query);
          $num = mysql_num_rows($result2);

          if($num == 1)
          {
             // return foreach with all results similar to the word thet write on the input.
          }else
          {
             // return wrong . no reuslts found
          }
```

This way working perfect with English words , when i using Hebrew words its not find nothing .

I did die to  `$string` ,and the word was perfecly writed in hebrew and on utf8 , all my database using utf8_general_ci , all my pages have meta with utf8 encoding , all my site working perfect with hebrew .

But here with this code when i try to search like somthing in Database with hebrew words always says not found , when i try in english its found , any idea ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you have to change collation of table....change it to utf-swedis

Comment: my table using utf8_genreal_ci and this way all my site working perfect with hebrew..

Comment: can you explain what is hebrew ?

Comment: hebrew is Israel / Jewish language using Windows-1255 encoding..

Comment: @Ravivg  you solved your problem ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page, probably, isn't encoded in UTF-8.

If it was, when you printed the message you shouldn't see the Hebrew characters (unless you set `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` before

(If the page is utf-8 encoded and you don't have this header, or other with `charset=utf-8` - you would get black rhombus signs with question marks).

If order to encode it in UTF-8 you can open it with Notapad++ and select:

Encoding -> Encode in UTF-8 Without BOM

Comment: I using utf8 everyone , and my pages all always first i doing is to save them as utf8 , all my Database using InnoDB and utf8_general_ci , and in my mysql i have charset utf8 correctly , and all my site using hebrew perfecly without any problems.. ,and all u write to me i have already and u can see even pic on my edit post

Answer (score 0):

Try this : first set your page to utf-8

```
  header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Also You need to do this

```
 mysql_query("ALTER DATABASE <mydatabasename>
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci");
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_fname like '%".$string."%' OR user_lname like        '%".$string."%' OR username like  '%".$string."%' OR useremail like '%".$string."%'";
```

Note: You can alter your table also for COLLATE and CHARACTER SET.

Comment: i have this header already, and my page is saved on utf8 encoding already. i tryed ur mysql_query thing and its still not working and always say there is no results..

Comment: there might be a problem in query execution.
try: 
mysql_query($query, $conn);
Also provide a second parameter in mysql_query() function as a connection variable to the database you are using

Comment: but i get results when i using words in english, its not find any results only when i  using hebrew letters